The action of the connection of endomorphism of vector bundles on a $k$-form
I am reading Huybrechts's book Complex Geometry An Introduction and feel confused about one small calculation in Lemma 4.4.4. He claims that if $\gamma\in \mathcal{A}^{k}(\operatorname{End}(E))$, where $E$ is a complex vector bundle with a connection $\nabla = d+A$, $A\in \mathcal{A}^1(M,\operatorname{End}(E))$,
$$
\nabla_{\operatorname{End}(E)}(\gamma) = d\gamma+[A,\gamma].
$$
However, it seems to me the action of $A$ on $\gamma$ is $A\wedge \gamma-(-1)^k \gamma\wedge A$. My calculation is as follows:
We can assume $E = M\times \mathbb{C}^r$. Then any section $\gamma\in \mathcal{A}^k(M,\operatorname{End}(E)) = Hom(\oplus \mathcal{A}_M^0,\oplus \mathcal{A}_M^k)$ is given by a $k$-form valued matrix $(\alpha_{ij}) = \sum_{i,j} \alpha_{ij}e_{ij}$. Then
$$
    \begin{align*}
        \nabla_{\operatorname{End}(E)}(\gamma)
        & = \sum_{i,j}\nabla(\alpha_{ij}e_{ij}) = \sum_{i,j}\left(d\alpha_{ij}\otimes e_{ij}+(-1)^k\alpha_{ij}\wedge \nabla(e_{ij})\right)\\
        & = d\gamma+(-1)^k\sum_{i,j} \alpha_{ij}\wedge (de_{i,j}+[A,e_{i,j}])\\
        & = d\gamma+(-1)^k\sum_{i,j} \alpha_{ij}\wedge (Ae_{i,j}-e_{i,j}A)\\
        & = d\gamma+A\wedge \sum_{i,j} \alpha_{i,j}e_{i,j}-(-1)^k (\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}e_{ij})A\\
        & = d\gamma+ A\wedge \gamma-(-1)^k\gamma \wedge A.
    \end{align*}
$$
Can someone tell if I was wrong, and if I was, what's the problem?

I think you are correct. Usually, the Lie bracket of two sections of $\mathcal A^\bullet(M, \mathrm{End} E)$ is defined as $[\alpha, \beta] = \alpha \wedge \beta - (-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(\alpha)\mathrm{deg}(\beta)}\beta \wedge \alpha$. You should look up the definition of the bracket in the book you are reading.
